# Does QThread::sleep() require the event loop to be running?

Tags: c++, qt, multithreading, sleep

I have a simple client-server program written in Qt, where processes communicate using MPI. The basic design I'm trying to implement is the following:

1. The first process (the "server") launches a GUI (derived from `QMainWindow`), which listens for messages from the clients (using repeat fire `QTimer`s and asynchronous MPI receive calls), updates the GUI depending on what messages it receives, and sends a reply to every message.
2. Every other process (the "clients") runs in an infinite loop, and all they are intended to do is send a message to the server process, receive the reply, go to sleep for a while, then wake up and repeat. Every process instantiates a single object derived from `QThread`, and calls its `start()` method. The `run()` method of these classes all look like this:

from foo.cpp:

```
void Foo::run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Send message to the first process
        // Wait for a reply
        // Do uninteresting stuff with the reply
        sleep(3);    // also tried QThread::sleep(3)
    }
}
```

In the client's code, there is no call to `exec()` anywhere, so no event loop should start.

The problem is that the clients never wake up from sleeping (if I surround the `sleep()` call with two writes to a log file, only the first one is executed, control never reaches the second). Is this because I didn't start the event loop? And if so, what is the simplest way to achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Some classes in client code may need an event loop to be started. Why to use QThreads for clients if you don't have an event loop for the clients and you already using MPI?

Comment: The only reason I'm deriving from `QThread` in the clients is because it gives me easy access to sleep functionality via `QThread::sleep()`. I'd like to avoid busy waiting.

Comment: exec is not necessarily bussy wait, from my wathcing fo CPOU comsumption it is not, there is something more smart behind (or your CPU will actually take all time 100%)

so go for exec and signal slot concept

Comment: I know `exec()` isn't busy waiting, I meant that I'd like to avoid waiting by, for example, starting a timer and then putting `while (timer.isActive()) {}` in the code. `QThread::sleep()` is the most convenient solution I could find.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner answer to the question is - sleep and event loop are not related.
Sleep makes the calling thread sleep irrespective of whether it's being called from thread's overridden `run()` function or any other function for that matter. It makes no difference and there is no escape.
In fact, if `exec()` is called somewhere in `run()` (which the QThread's default implementation is) the control will not return to the caller.

The reason for the second log statement not getting written cannot be directly related with `sleep()` if the logger object is local or available to the `run()` function all the time. The control has to return to thread after designated amount of sleep is done. But meanwhile, the thread could lose control to transient objects like incoming connection.

Perhaps when this question was asked QThread::sleep() was a private function. Now with Qt 5, [sleep](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#sleep) or [msleep](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#msleep) or even [usleep](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#usleep) are public static functions.